# Not able to import tensorflow on anaconda with python 3.6 version on 64bit system with 64bit anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

When I import tensorflow it gives me this error:

> > > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > >           File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
> > > >             from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> > > >           File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
> > > >             _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
> > > >           File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
> > > >             _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
> > > >           File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
> > > >             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
> > > >           File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
> > > >             return _load(spec)
> > > >         ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import tensorflow as tf   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py",
>   line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

Please Help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The following might me the problems :

- You have not installed Microsoft C++ Redist 2015 Update 3. It contains the missing dll. You need to download the 2015 update 3 version only.
- Your CPU doesn't support AVX instructions which are needed by TensorFlow. You will need a processer which supports AVX.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this same issue with my system (Win 10, 64 bit). Following are the details of how I resolved this issue:

1. Install **VS 2017**, tensorflow doesn't use it but having it helps in the smooth installation of CUDA toolkit.
2. Update **NVDIA driver from windows device manager**.
3. Download and Install **CUDA toolkit (version 10.1)**.
4. Download and unzip **CUDnn 7.6.5**. Copy the extracted files into a folder in C drive.
5. Add `~\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin`, `~\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin` and `cudnn-10.1-windows10-x64-v7.6.4.38\cuda\bin` to PATH

Doing `import tensorflow as tf` after the above steps solved the issue.