# Cannot import tensorflow in Spyder

Tags: tensorflow, keras, spyder, importerror, python-3.8

When I run `import keras` in Spyder, the error message states that keras cannot find a tensorflow with version > 2.2

When I run `import tensorflow`, I get the following error message:

> File "C:\Users\*xxx*\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
> from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Det går inte att hitta den angivna modulen.

(Last message in local tribal language translates as "Can not find the specified module")

I have installed keras and tensorflow via Anaconda using pip. The tensorflow version installed is 2.4.0, Keras 2.4.3 and Python 3.8

If I look in the folder **C:\Users\*xxx*\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_pywrap_tensorflow_internal**, there is a file called **_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.lib**
I am not a Python expert, but I am guessing this file contains the binary code that should be called when the error is thrown ? The folder **C:\Users\*xxx*\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages** is added to the Python path manager from within Spyder-

I used to being able to run Keras with this computer (Windows 10, x64). But since I formatted the hard drive and reinstalled everything from scratch it does not work. No GPU involved.

Sidenote: Some replies ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946205/importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-pywrap-tensorflow-internal-the-sp), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921175/not-able-to-import-tensorflow-on-anaconda-with-python-3-6-version-on-64bit-syste)) to similar questions on this site suggests it has to do with the Visual studio distribution. I have installed VS 2015, previously I used VS 2019. I would prefere not to install VS 2019 if it can be avoided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistrutable Update 3 solved the problem. I think I found it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685)